# Documentviewer as standard

Tags: 14.04

After installing Gimp, all PDF files are opened with Gimp instead of Documentviewer (as they used to be). How to change that in Preferences?? I can find the program.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by right-clicking a pdf document, selecting properties in the menu, then open with. In that list, you should find Documentviewer.

Comment: You tried to edit my answer in order to reply. Please use comments instead. I didn't understand why you can't run Documentviewer. Are you unable to run it from the Dash?

Comment: The property-menu Brings only the use of Gimp (standard) or other... When I click on other, I don't know where to find the Documentviewer

Comment: At the bottom of the dialog, there is a very wide button labeled something like "Show other applications"? If you click it, you should get a long list. One of them should be Documentviewer.